# OMXPLAYER - display subtitle language

Tags: omxplayer

Is it possible to display on OSD the subtitle language or the subtitle filename of a video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Put that information in the subtitle file itself as the first caption. For instance, here's how you add captions to an [SRT file](https://www.3playmedia.com/2017/03/08/create-srt-file/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. With this workaround is it possible to display the suntitle language on OSD during all the video?

Comment: @Erebus You could write a script (or a regular expression in your editor) adding a line with the subtitle language to every caption.

Comment: I'm newbie on this. How can I do that? Can You give me an example how to create a script/REGEX to add a line with subtiltile language on osd? Thanks in advance